# how to popup zoom in animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I need to apply many types of animations on a popup using pure CSS and javascript. I understand that I should use `transition` and `transform`. But I face a problem with applying this. (it gives me no animation)

here is my attempt `zoom in`.

```js
function zoomIn(){
document.getElementById('layout').classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
.layout{
  position: fixed;
  inset:0;
  
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  
  display: none;
  transition: transform 250ms, opacity 400ms;
}
.layout img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;  
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.show {
  display: block;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="zoomIn()" style="padding:20px">zoom in</button>

<div id="layout" class="layout">
<img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/illustrations/king-lion-aslan-illustration-id458017717?k=20&m=458017717&s=612x612&w=0&h=4qOseLgTPV5ZOEoZD2scNzf-LQ7AWoRXtbidR61OhG8=" width="400" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nice example here - https://codepen.io/notdarryltec/full/YPOKdb/   https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/animating-simple-css-popup-tutorial/

Comment: Better implementation of popup with css and html

Comment: Oh sorry @Thescion The link was busted for me before so I was redirected to another location, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display none and block property can not be animated unfortunately. Your code looks good otherwise, so in this case you need to use `visibility: visible; and visibility: hidden;`. Like this:

```js
function zoomIn(){
document.getElementById('layout').classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
.layout{
  position: fixed;
  inset:0;
 visibility:hidden;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  transition: transform 250ms, opacity 400ms;
}
.layout img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;  
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   
}
.show {
  transform: scale(1.2);
    visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="zoomIn()" style="padding:20px">zoom in</button>

<div id="layout" class="layout">
<img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/illustrations/king-lion-aslan-illustration-id458017717?k=20&m=458017717&s=612x612&w=0&h=4qOseLgTPV5ZOEoZD2scNzf-LQ7AWoRXtbidR61OhG8=" width="400" />
</div>
```